# Presort points in closest pair to achieve O(nlogn) instead of O(nlog^2n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

In Closest Pair algorithm, it is said that presorting points according to x and y coordinates can help decrease time complexibility from O(nlog^2n) to O(nlogn), but how can that happen? I think presort also requires O(nlogn) time rather than O(n), so the equation is still T(n)=2T(n/2)+O(nlogn).

Can anyone show how to complete presort in details to achieve O(n)? Or do I have any misunderstandings about it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem 

You need to sort points only once in the beginning. So, your equation is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to what you're referring to as "presort", but the algorithm is *O(n log(n))*, according to [these steps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem#Planar_case):

1. First, sort according to the *x* coordinate.
2. Recursively, divide into two, similarly-sized sets, divided by an *x<sub>m</sub>* value.

   a. solve for each of the left and right subsets to *x<sub>m</sub>*.

   b. for each of the points on the left, find the closest points in a bounded rectangle containing points to the right (see details in link above); same for the points on the right.

   c. return the minimum of the smallest distances found in b.

Step 1 is *O(n log(n)*. Step 2 is given by *T(n) = 2 T(n / 2) + Θ(n)*.

Comment: I see! So the algorithm is divided into two parts. I thought that the deduction was still T(n)=T(n/2) + O(nlogn). Many thanks!